# reading memory offset with GDB [GAS]

Tags: assembly, gdb, gnu-assembler

How can I read the following memory address with GDB :

```
0x30(%rsp,%rdx,4)
```

I've tried :

```
x/[s/d] 0x30 + ($rsp + $rdx + 4)
```

However, the results are not at all what I expected to find.
Apologies if this is a duplicate - I couldn't find a matching question via search.

Answer (score 1):

You need multiply $rdx by 4:

```
x/d $rsp + $rdx * 4+0x30
```